# Notation of invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, definition

Let $X$ be a $n \times p$ matrix that satisfies that $M = X^T X$, which is $p\times p$ matrix, is invertible.

Is there a standard notation/definition for this kind of matrices?

I just want to know if there is a name for such matrices, e.g. **those are Tupac matrices**, or something along those lines.

Comment: @littleO Thanks, that is helpful. I would accept your comment as an answer if you want to post it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix $M = X^T X$ would be a [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix). The invertibility condition would be saying the corresponding inner product $\langle x, y\rangle := (Ax)^T (Ay) = x^T (A^T A) y$ is non-degenerate.

The matrix $X$, where the condition is that $X^T X$ is invertible, would just be any (real) matrix with linearly independent columns, or equivalently one which represents an injective linear transformation. This is not *quite* the same as $X$ being full rank. For instance, $X = (1\ 2)$ has full rank (namely 1) but the columns are not linearly independent and $X^TX$ has rank $1$, not $2$.